# R - Date in a bad format - LMT format

Tags: r, rmysql, as.date

From R I read data into a MySQL database. There is a date column.
The problem is the result is very very bad.

`head(inputd$Semaine_lundi, n=20)
 [1] "-1-12-09 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-16 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-16 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-23 00:13:36 LMT"
 [5] "-1-12-30 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-06 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-13 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-20 00:13:36 LMT"
 [9] "-1-12-27 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-30 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-30 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-30 00:13:36 LMT"
[13] "-1-12-30 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-30 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-30 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-07 00:13:36 LMT"
[17] "-1-12-07 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-07 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-07 00:13:36 LMT" "-1-12-07 00:13:36 LMT"`

I have never seen this before and no conversion method such as as.Date or as.POSIXct worked.
How to solve it please ?

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hms(x)
#[1] "2009-12-01 00:13:36 UTC"
```

#### data

```
x <- "-1-12-09 00:13:36 LMT"
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. In MySQL, the date is for example **2012-01-09 00:00:00** and when I read data, in R is become **-1-12-09 00:13:36 LMT**. So the hour has changed and the date format too. As output, I have **2009-12-01 00:13:36 WAT**. Even when I change the format parameters, the result it's wrong

Comment: @MaelElvisFosso  Please check the str(yourdata) and also post the dput output of a small example